# How do I convert JSON to YAML in ruby without using CMD line?

Tags: json, ruby, api, yaml, backend

I am trying to implement JSON to YAML in ruby I would like to know how can I achieve this by ruby Code

** Not Like this**

```
ruby -ryaml -rjson -e 'puts YAML.dump(JSON.load(ARGF))' < example.json > example.yml
```

** Something like this ... **

```
require 'json'

filepath = "./response.json"
directory_name = "read"

directory_name = "read"
Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)

if File.file?(filepath)  
    storageJson = JSON.parse(File.read(filepath)).fetch('items', []).sort_by { |event| event['startTime'] }

---- Something like this ... -----
```

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON so you don't need to do anything, a JSON file will load as YAML. If your goal is to have block-style YAML, why don't you just do `YAML.dump(JSON.load(…))` like on the command line? And what is your actual problem with your *Something like this* code?

Comment: I think you confused python syntax with ruby. This `if` will need an `end`.

What exactly are you struggling with at the moment? Is there any exception that you don't understand? Or do you want to write your own `YAML.dump` method?

Comment: I was able to figure out later that. ".to_yaml" is an inbuilt method available when we require "yaml" in my ruby script. Thanks for your response.